# CUDA can't use all available constant memory

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have a code that uses cooperative group to perform some operations. Therefore I compile my code with:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -arch=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61, --device-c -g -O2 foo.cu
```

Then I try to invoke the device linker:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -arch=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61, -g -dlink foo.o
```

It then yields the error:

> ptxas error : File uses too much global constant data (0x10100 bytes, 0x10000 max)

The problem is caused by the way I allocated constant memory:

```
__constant__ float d_cnst_centers[CONST_MEM / sizeof(float)];
```

where CONST_MEM = 65536 bytes, which I got from device query for SM_61. However, if I reduce the constant memory to something like 64536, the problem disappeared. It's almost as if the constant memory is "reserved" for some purposes during compilation. I've searched through CUDA documentation but didn't find a satisfying answer. Is it safe to use the maximum amount of constant memory available to you? Why would this problem happen?

EDIT: this is the code snippet that triggers the error on SM_61:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>

#include <cooperative_groups.h>

using namespace cooperative_groups;


struct foo_params {
    float * points;
    float * centers;
    int * centersDist;
    int * centersIndex;
    int numPoints;
};

__constant__ float d_cnst_centers[65536 / sizeof(float)];

template <int R, int C>
__device__ int 
nearestCenter(float * points, float * pC) {
    float mindist = FLT_MAX;
    int minidx = 0;
    int clistidx = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<C;i++) {
        clistidx = i*R;
        float dist;
        {
            float *point = points;
            float *center = &pC[clistidx];
            float accum;
            for(int i = 0; i<R; i++) {
                float delta = point[i] - center[i];
                accum += delta*delta;
            }
            dist = sqrt(accum);
        }
        /* ... */
    }
    return minidx;
}


template<int R, int C, bool bRO, bool ROWMAJ=true>
__global__ void getNeatestCenter(struct foo_params params) {
        float * points = params.points;
        float * centers = params.centers;
        int * centersDist = params.centersDist;
        int * centersIndex = params.centersIndex;
        int numPoints = params.numPoints;

        grid_group grid = this_grid();
        {
            int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
            if (idx < numPoints) {
                centersIndex[idx] = nearestCenter<R,C>(&points[idx*R], d_cnst_centers);
            }
        }
        /* ... other code */
}

int main () {
    // foo paramaters, for illustration purposes
    struct foo_params param;
    param.points = NULL;
    param.centers = NULL;
    param.centersDist = NULL;
    param.centersIndex = NULL;
    param.numPoints = 1000000;
    void *p_params = &param;

    int minGridSize = 0, blockSize = 0;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(
                            &minGridSize,
                            &blockSize,
                            (void*)getNeatestCenter<128, 64, true>,
                            0,
                            0);

    dim3 dimGrid(minGridSize, 1, 1), dimBlock(blockSize, 1, 1);

    cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void *)getNeatestCenter<32, 32, true>, dimGrid, dimBlock, &p_params);
}
```

The problem seems to be cause by the line:

```
grid_group grid = this_grid();
```

which seems to use approximately 0x100 bytes of constant memory without known reasons.

Comment: I suppose your code is larger than that. If the compiler does not have enough registers for the kernel I think it just allocates a bit of constant memory to store those values. I suspect that might be the issue. Not your constant allocation, but well, the rest of the code. In any case, using the entirety of the memory, to the last byte, its probably not a good idea in general.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The compiler doesn't do that

Comment: I do have a macro trick that allocates hundreds if not thousands of functions headers and their corresponding implementations. Do function headers some how use constant memory? This problem didn't exist when I compile without rdc set to true.

Comment: @talonmies I think I have already asked you this in the past: The only reason I do believe you is because you are a bit of an authoritative source in CUDA in Stackoverflow, but without that, just claiming something is wrong without any further explanation adds zero to 1) me to learn why I am wrong 2)To the OP who is here to fix a problem. Please, I ask you again: can you explain your claims, rather than add noise. I genuinely ask, I do want to be proven wrong when I am, being _proven_ the key word.

Comment: The compiler spills to local memory. And there is a *dedicated* constant memory bank which is used for kernel arguments and compile time constants. The user controllable constant memory bank is totally separate. And  ptxas will show you precisely how much of each is used when you compile code. And I will point the precise same complaint at you: It isn't helpful to speculate about something. You either know it or you don't. Signal to noise ratio is key in a place like this. Misinformation has a life of its own. Think about it

Comment: @talonmies Is there a specific section in CUDA doc or the programming guide that explains this? I'd like to know exactly what happened under the hood.

Comment: Here is an example of allocating 65536 bytes of constant memory: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/pWPAHW . So it works. The code and/or verbose compiler output would be a valuable addition to your question. And to understand how this works you basically need to read the PTX guide and the nvcc guide cover to cover, unfortunately

Comment: @talonmies well, *I though* I did know, obviously I am not just just randomly adding arbitrary information on random SO posts... I am surprised you assume the opposite. This is why I ask you for clarification and prof, otherwise its a "I say you say" situation...

Comment: @edhu: There has to be some additional constant memory usage somewhere which the linker is picking up and combining into an allocation which spills over. Exactly where is between you and your code. This godbolt is basically the use case you show in the question, and you can see it works https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/78pfj5

Comment: @edhu Some math functions use a small table internally, and therefore require a small amount of constant memory from the same constant bank as the programmer's code. An example would be `sinf()`. Please show minimal reproducable example code so we can verify whether this case applies.

Comment: @edhu: Best I can tell, `sqrt` does not require any constant memory.

Comment: @njuffa You are right. The grid_group grid = this_grid(); seems to be the problem instead. But I will take the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is *speculative*, because minimal but complete repro code was not provided by OP.

GPUs contain multiple constant memory banks used for different parts of program storage. One of those banks is for use by the programmer. Importantly, CUDA standard math library code uses the same bank, because the math library code becomes part of the programmer's code by function inlining. In the past, this was blatantly obvious, as the entire CUDA math library initially was just a couple of header files.

Some math functions need small tables of constant data internally. Particular examples are `sin`, `cos`, `tan`. When these math functions are used, the amount of `__constant__` data available to programmers is reduced from 64KB by a small amount. Here are some example programs for demonstration purposes, compiled with the CUDA 8 toolchain and `-arch=sm_61`:

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONST_MEM (65536)
__constant__ float d_cnst_centers[CONST_MEM / sizeof(float)] = {1};

__global__ void kernel (int i, float f)
{
    float r = d_cnst_centers[i] * expf(f);
    printf ("r=%15.8f\n", r);
}

int main (void)
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(0,25.0f);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This compiles fine and prints `r=72004902912.00000000` at run time. Now lets change `expf` into `sinf`:

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONST_MEM (65536)
__constant__ float d_cnst_centers[CONST_MEM / sizeof(float)] = {1};

__global__ void kernel (int i, float f)
{
    float r = d_cnst_centers[i] * sinf(f);
    printf ("r=%15.8f\n", r);
}

int main (void)
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(0,25.0f);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This throws an error during compilation:
`ptxas error   : File uses too much global constant data (0x10018 bytes, 0x10000 max)`

If we use the double-precision function `sin` instead, even more constant memory is needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONST_MEM (65536)
__constant__ float d_cnst_centers[CONST_MEM / sizeof(float)] = {1};

__global__ void kernel (int i, float f)
{
    float r = d_cnst_centers[i] * sin((double)f);
    printf ("r=%15.8f\n", r);
}

int main (void)
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(0,25.0f);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

We get the error message:
`ptxas error   : File uses too much global constant data (0x10110 bytes, 0x10000 max)`

Comment: A follow-up question. If the kernel is launched normally without using cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel() call, and comment out the grid_group line, then the problem disappeared. Why would cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel() cause extra use of constant memory in this case?

Comment: @edhu Don't know. I already had to speculate what the issue *might* be, I am not going to speculate any further. FWIW, I don't think `sqrt` needs any constant memory.

Comment: I updated the post with a reproducible example. The speculation seems to be exactly where my problem was. But thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In order to document what exactly is happening in this use case, I have cobbled together the following work through of the compilation process. Hopefully it will shed some light on how this problem arises, and some useful diagnostic tools, and dispel  a few misconceptions at the same time.

**Note this is a work in progress and may be updated periodically as more information comes to light. Please edit and contribute as you see fit**

To start, as noted in comments, it is perfectly possible to allocate every byte of constant memory up until the 64kb limit. This example is pretty much the use case described in the original question:

```
const int sz = 65536;
const int NMax = sz / sizeof(float);
__constant__ float buffer[NMax];

__global__ 
void akernel(const float* __restrict__ arg1, float* __restrict__ arg2, int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < N) {
        float ans = 0;
        #pragma unroll 128
        for(int i=0; i<NMax; i++)  {
            float val = buffer[i];
            float y = (i%2 == 0) ? 1.f : -1.f;
            float x = val / 255.f;
            ans = ans + y * sinf(x);
        }
        arg2[tid] = ans + arg1[tid];
    }
}
```

and it compiles without a problem (Godbolt link [here](https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/3brBw2)). This proves that the linker phase in the question must be pulling in additional constant memory allocations from other code, whether that is user code, other device libraries, or device runtime support.

So let's turn our attention to the repro case posted in the updated question, mildly modified so that it will pass the compilation and link phase by reducing the constant memory footprint slightly, with a buffer of 64536 bytes:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 --device-c -g -O2 -Xptxas="-v" -o constmemuse.cu.o constmemuse.cu 
constmemuse.cu(51): warning: variable "centers" was declared but never referenced

constmemuse.cu(52): warning: variable "centersDist" was declared but never referenced

constmemuse.cu(31): warning: variable "dist" was set but never used
          detected during instantiation of "void getNeatestCenter<R,C,bRO,ROWMAJ>(foo_params) [with R=128, C=64, bRO=true, ROWMAJ=true]" 

constmemuse.cu(26): warning: variable "mindist" was declared but never referenced
          detected during instantiation of "void getNeatestCenter<R,C,bRO,ROWMAJ>(foo_params) [with R=128, C=64, bRO=true, ROWMAJ=true]" 

ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem, 64536 bytes cmem[3]
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaDeviceGetAttribute
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z16getNeatestCenterILi128ELi64ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params' for 'sm_61'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z16getNeatestCenterILi128ELi64ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaMalloc
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaGetDevice
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z16getNeatestCenterILi32ELi32ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params' for 'sm_61'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z16getNeatestCenterILi32ELi32ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaFuncGetAttributes
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessorWithFlags
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
```

A few points:

- `64536 bytes cmem[3]` shows the size of the user controllable constant memory bank, as we specified it
- `ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0]` shows the register usage of the function and `cmem[0]` is the internal reserved constant memory bank which is used for holding kernel arguments and anything else which the compiler puts to constant memory. Note that register spilling goes to local memory, not constant memory.

So now let's run the device linking step:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61, -g -dlink -Xnvlink="-v" -o constmemuse.o constmemuse.cu.o

nvlink info    : 9944 bytes gmem, 64792 bytes cmem[3] (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 20 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 23 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 28 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 23 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 448 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 10 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 12 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 17 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 14 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 16 registers, 0 stack, 2056 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 16 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 14 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 17 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 8 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 11 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 12 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 11 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 21 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 424 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '_Z16getNeatestCenterILi32ELi32ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 360 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : Function properties for '_Z16getNeatestCenterILi128ELi64ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params': (target: sm_61)
nvlink info    : used 6 registers, 0 stack, 0 bytes smem, 360 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem (target: sm_61)
```

Some more remarks:

- `9944 bytes gmem, 64792 bytes cmem[3]` now shows the global and constant memory reservations for the linked module. As you can see, we have inherited 256 additional bytes in constant bank 0, which is the user modifiable bank, plus 9944 bytes of statically reserved global memory. If the array allocation had been 65536 bytes, as in the question, the linkage will fail because it exceeds the 64kb limit.
- You can see that a number of device runtime library functions have been linked automagically during the linkage phase (memcpy and memset)

It is clear that the additional constant memory usage is coming linking the device runtime, it can be confirmed with `cuobjdump` post hoc. The object from compilation:

```
$ cuobjdump -res-usage constmemuse.cu.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed

Resource usage:
 Common:
  GLOBAL:0 CONSTANT[3]:64536
 Function cudaDeviceGetAttribute:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function _Z16getNeatestCenterILi128ELi64ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:360 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function cudaMalloc:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function cudaGetDevice:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function _Z16getNeatestCenterILi32ELi32ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:360 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function cudaFuncGetAttributes:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessorWithFlags:
  REG:5 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0

Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [6,4]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
ptxasOptions = -v --compile-only
```

and the object after linking:

```
$ cuobjdump -res-usage constmemuse.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

Resource usage:
 Common:
  GLOBAL:9944 CONSTANT[3]:64792
 Function _Z16getNeatestCenterILi128ELi64ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:360 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function _Z16getNeatestCenterILi32ELi32ELb1ELb1EEv10foo_params:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:360 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:21 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:11 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 CONSTANT[2]:4 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:12 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 CONSTANT[2]:4 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:11 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:8 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:400 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:17 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:14 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:16 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memset_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPhhjT_S1_S1_S1_S1_jjjjjjjS1_S0_:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:424 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:16 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 CONSTANT[2]:4 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:14 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 CONSTANT[2]:4 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:17 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:12 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceIjLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:416 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:23 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:28 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:23 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi0ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:20 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi0ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi0EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function __nv_static_51__38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_75_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37__Z16memcpy_3d_deviceImLi1ELi1ELi1EEvPKhPhT_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_jjjjjjjjS3_S1_S2_:
  REG:10 STACK:0 SHARED:2056 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:448 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function cudaCGGetIntrinsicHandle:
  REG:6 STACK:0 SHARED:0 LOCAL:0 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
```

It has been demonstrated in the accepted answer that the math library can reserve constant memory for coefficients and lookup tables for some trigonometric and transcendental functions. However, in this case, the cause seems to be the support boilerplate emitted by the use of cooperative groups in the kernel. Delving further into the exact source of the additional bank 0 constant memory would require disassembly and reverse engineering of that code, which I am not going to do for now.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something basic here, but as I was playing around with your first code, I noticed that you can change `sz` to any positive value in the Godbolt example and it compiles successfully anyway. But the code with `sz = 65536` fails to compile on my Windows and Linux machine `sm_61` complaining about the usage of too much constant memory.